# Check if any of the textboxes is empty wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling, wpf-controls

Is there any way to iterate through all the textboxes to see if any of the textboxes is empty? I want the user to enter values in all textboxes. Suppose the *event handler* has the following code:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //check if textboxes are empty
            if (/*logic here for checking*/)

                MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in all the fields");
            else
            {//send values entered to other window.
                Window1 w1 = new Window1(customername.Text, "", "", "", Phoneno.Text, Symptoms.Text, Total.Text, datepick);

                this.Hide();
                this.Owner.Show();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Better: disable the Button as long as any TextBox is empty.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This code should work:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (gridcontrol.Children
        .OfType<TextBox>()
        .Any(tb => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in all the fields");
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively use IsNullOrWhiteSpace